# Does Xcode 5 supports which Application Loader Version?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am unable to upload through 2.7 version of Application Loader, after 3 hours, i did through 2.9 version Application Loader? My doubt is does Xcode 5 supports which Application Loader versions?

Comment: May I ask why don't you publish it directly through Xcode organizer?

Comment: What's the relationship between Xcode and Application Loader? Unless Xcode 5 is now generating invalid apps, then I don't understand the connection.

Comment: It's take some time, so i preferred Apploader, but through Xcode organiser also works fine.